# Integration Problem Through Parts or u-substitution?

Tags: calculus

I have this integral I need to solve, and I am not sure if I did this correctly, or how to do it even if this way isn't correct.

$$
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+5}} dx
$$

I've tried to do it through integration by parts, but it doesn't seem to make it much easier. I am not very good with the math notation on here so I can't really show you what I tried but I've tried setting $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+5}}$ and $dv = x dx$.

Comment: Let $x+5=u$, then $x=u-5$ and you will get $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+5}}=\frac{u-5}{\sqrt{u}}=u^{0.5}-5u^{-0.5}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+5}}dx=\int \frac{x+5}{\sqrt{x+5}}dx-\int \frac{5}{\sqrt{x+5}}dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{x+5}dx-\int \frac{5}{\sqrt{x+5}}dx$$
$$=\frac23(x+5)^\frac32-10\sqrt{x+5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use integration by parts, but let $$u=x$$ and $$v=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+5}}$$
The integration comes to be $$\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x+5}-\int\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x+5}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x+5}-\frac{1}{2}*\frac{2}{3}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x+5}-\frac{1}{3}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

With integration by parts, make the part that will become simpler when derived the u term and the rest the v term. A helpful hint.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you let $u=x+5$, as suggested in the comment above, then you have $x=u-5$ and $dx=du$,

so the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int\frac{u-5}{\sqrt{u}}du=\int\big(u^\frac{1}{2}-5u^{-\frac{1}{2}}\big)\; du$.

2) If you let $u=\sqrt{x+5}$, then $x=u^2-5$ and $dx=2udu$,

so the integral becomes
$\displaystyle\int\frac{u^2-5}{u}\cdot(2u)du=2\int(u^2-5)\;du.$